# Copy worksheet to another workbook and close the source worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've found the below code which works nearly as id like to.
However when i go to copy the **pivot data worksheet** and specifically paste it in the tab called *"Data"* in the **Resource Costing...xls** i cant seem to make it work. 
Also once its copied how do i close the excel file that it was copied from? Any help, advice is much appreciated.

```
Sub OpenLatestResourceForecastFile()
'Declare the variables
Dim MyPath As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim LatestFile As String
Dim LatestDate As Date
Dim LMD As Date
Dim MyData As Workbook
Set CopiedData = Workbooks("Resource Costing E3.xlsm").Sheets(4)
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook


'Specify the path to the folder
MyPath = "C\doc etc"

'Make sure that the path ends in a backslash
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then MyPath = MyPath & "\"

'Get the first Excel file from the folder
MyFile = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls", vbNormal)

'If no files were found, exit the sub
If Len(MyFile) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No files were found...", vbExclamation
    Exit Sub
End If

'Loop through each Excel file in the folder
Do While Len(MyFile) > 0

    'Assign the date/time of the current file to a variable
    LMD = FileDateTime(MyPath & MyFile)

    'If the date/time of the current file is greater than the latest
    'recorded date, assign its filename and date/time to variables
    If LMD > LatestDate Then
        LatestFile = MyFile
        LatestDate = LMD
    End If

    'Get the next Excel file from the folder
    MyFile = Dir

Loop

'Open the latest file and copy Pivot Data Tab
Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile
Worksheets("Pivot Data").Copy After:=CopiedData

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Code Below i an Example how you can close the Workbook. Use a variable for the Workbook you are going to Open. After that you can close it without Saving it.

```
Dim wbLatestFile As Workbook

'Open the latest file and copy Pivot Data Tab
Set wbLatestFile = Workbooks.Open MyPath & LatestFile
wbLatestFile .Worksheets("Pivot Data").Copy After:=CopiedData

wbLatestFile.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Comment: Thank you, ill try it out now. I did suspect it having to with defining the variables.